# Can we have external dependency within the company's codebase?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, external-dependencies

We have a dependency in package.json for npm install. However, in our current environment, we can't access websites like github.com. So, I cloned the project into our codebase and updated package.json to use it from there instead. Do you think this change might cause any issues? Here's what package.json looks like now:

Before: "samlp": "github:mcguinness/node-samlp",

After: "samlp": "file: ./idp/node-samlp","